# Like Button error click (Int)0?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

When you click on the button goes (Int)0.Can someone tell me how to solve this error? I tried without connecting to the server, this method worked.I need help help.What is the reason for this error? did the lesson appcoda Like Instagramm.

```
 import UIKit

class CustomSoccerHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {


    var saveBravo: Soccer?

    @IBOutlet weak var bravoBtn: UIButton! {
        didSet {
            bravoBtn.layer.cornerRadius = bravoBtn.frame.size.width/2
            bravoBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true

        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var countBravo: UILabel!


    @IBAction func saveClick(_ sender: UIButton) {


        if (saveBravo != nil) {

            if var clickBravissimo: Int = saveBravo!.object(forKey: "bravissimo") as? Int {

                clickBravissimo += 1

                saveBravo!.setObject(clickBravissimo, forKey: "bravissimo")
                saveBravo!.saveInBackground()

            }

        }
    }






    @IBOutlet weak var nameHeader: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageHeader: UIImageView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code



    }


    }
```

Comment: `let soccerClick = Soccer()` creates a new object.  i'm guessing that you want to add one to an existing object instead, but you don't show how those `Soccer` objects are referenced.

Comment: Yes, you quite correctly understood me. How to make that for object it was kept?